# How do I push HTML from an error message to the React DOM w/o using jQuery targeting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to force the page to not load the login page if the username is taken/the password is too short or too long, as well as display the error message from the server describing what the issue with the sign up is. The problem is, I have little experience in React and I can't seem to figure out how to push that error message to the DOM without using jQuery class targeting.

Again, I've only tried jQuery because that's really the only way I know how to push an error message to the DOM.

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  this.props.history.push("/login");
})
.catch(error => {
  event.preventDefault();
  {$('.username-password-error-message').html(${error.message})}
});
```

This was my best attempt. Messy, I know. I tried to prevent default, but I have a feeling that won't work because my command to push the /login route from the props history in the then statement. I am expecting the page to not load the /login route and to push the error message relating to username and password problems to the DOM underneath the sign-in form. Again, I know this is extremely wrong, just couldn't seem to find what I needed through googling and stack overflow searches. Any help would be much appreciated for this React noob!

Answer (score 0):

Search for/get some inspiration from `'react autocomplete'` or `'react autosuggest'` tutorials.

This kind of functionality should be done as `'async validation'` - not within submit handler. Dont reinvent the wheel, read some [docs](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/validation#form-level-validation), search for examples.

IMHO 'manual' managing state (using `setState`) isn't worth the effort (for majority of this kind of use cases).

Comment: I have searched quite a bit and have read all of the basic React Docs. I am a brand new React user and am trying to complete a project for a scholastic setting so I'm trying to narrow the scope of reference into technologies I can work with. Formik, unfortunately, is foreign to me, and I actually just read here that the preferred method is to use submit validation: https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/asyncvalidation/.  As this is a scholastic setting, I want to learn how to do it within the scope of React and submit handlers, so I have that knowledge.